# Change deploy location for solution published using web deploy

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, msbuild, webdeploy

For a long time I have been performing dated deploys to our IIS servers, basically this means that each deploy gets its own dated folder within the web site folder (c:\sites\my-site\20140824-1236 for example).  I then redirect the web app to the new deployment folder.

This gives us a quick role back capability if things go pear shaped.

The problem is that we are looking at moving deployment over to the new web deploy techniques, while we have been using the new techniques within QA and UAT for a while - the standard behaviour is to simply replace the files at the location defined within the IIS web site.

Before I go and start looking at remote PowerShell to re-configure IIS before executing the web deploy.. does anyone know how I can achieve this using standard web deploy.. maybe with msbuild extensions or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the automatic backup capabilities in Web Deploy v3?

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups